# Where is the Makefile generated by the Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've built a hello world C++ project with Eclipse(helios) CDT. It compiled fine. But I would like to take a look at the Makefile CDT generated. I can't find it in project folder/debug/release folders or in the src folders. Where can I find this Makefile?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use the default setttings with `current builder = CDT internal builder`, there is no make file.
if you select `current builder = GNU make`, you will see the makefile in the debug folder.

Comment: I have no debug folder

Answer (score 19):

On Windows,

Click your project, go to menu `project` -> `properties`, select `Tool Chain Editor` then select in `Current Builder` `Gnu Make Builder`.

Build a target now generate makefile.

[image: Current builder Gnu Make Builder]

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can think of is that the makefile isn't created. Click your project, go to menu `project` -> `properties`, select `C/C++ Build` in the left pane, and make sure the `Generate Makefiles automatically` checkbox is checked.

Comment: Then what? When should the makefile popup?

Answer (score 5):

By default you should have [workspace]/[project folder]/Debug/**makefile**.  Have you made any changes to the default environment?

Here's the HelloWorld sample project makefile from a Helios (windows/cygwin) installation:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables

# All Target
all: HelloWorld.exe

# Tool invocations
HelloWorld.exe: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
        @echo 'Building target: $@'
        @echo 'Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker'
        g++  -o"HelloWorld.exe" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
        @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
        -$(RM) $(C++_DEPS)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) HelloWorld.exe
        -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: thanks.I did a search on the whole computer and cannot find the one. It might be generated on the fly and deleted automatically?

Comment: That's strange.  Even after I clean all my CDT projects, their makefiles don't get deleted.